# Collect some missing lines of a log file with logstash

Tags: logstash

How to collect new lines of a log file if we stop logstash in a fixed period and  after we restart it? knowing that:

```
start_position => 'end'
```

Answer (score 0):

[As documented](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/file#start_position), the file input's `start_position` parameter only controls what happens the first time Logstash encounters a file. Once the first contact is made, Logstash only uses its internal bookmark stored in the sincedb file.

In other words, it's generally fine to restart or shut down Logstash a little while. It'll pick up everything when it starts up again. There are two caveats though:

- If the logfile is rotated via a rename operation (which is the default in most cases) while Logstash is down and the filename pattern(s) don't cover the rotated file, the last lines will be lost. For this reason it's a good easy to have Logstash track the first rotated file too, so if you e.g. want to track /var/log/syslog and that file is rotated to /var/log/syslog.1 every morning it's wise to include both files.
- Logstash 1.4.2 doesn't shut down gracefully if it receives a SIGTERM signal. All messages currently in the 20-message buffer will be lost. Additionally, I'm not sure the sincedb file is flushed. Sending SIGINT will ensure a graceful shutdown.

Comment: Your answer seems very interesting, but as a beginner I do not really understand a lot, I don't know if you can give me some examples, maybe i will understand you.  Thanks a lot

Comment: @Morito: Sorry, I don't understand. What is unclear, and what type of example are you looking for? Continuously picking up new lines from the end of log files is what Logstash does by default so no special configuration is needed.

Comment: thank  a lot you the time that you have given for me, In this  moment it causes me any problem, maybe later, but now I'm stuck here, i don't know if you can help me :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29556622/missing-and-some-different-data-in-a-few-lines-in-my-log-file